# Enabling cuda support for opencv

Tags: python, windows, opencv

My goal is to enable the cuda support for opencv.I followed the guide from https://jamesbowley.co.uk/build-opencv-4-0-0-with-cuda-10-0-and-intel-mkl-tbb-in-windows/ or
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TT3_dlPL4vo
However, after complilation times, there's some error with it and i can't make it succesfully.Did anyone encountered this problem before and can share the solution of it?

[image]

> "D:\opencvcuda\opencv-master\build\INSTALL.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
>   (PostBuildEvent target) ->
>     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(
>   149,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal [D:\opencvcuda\opencv-master\build\INSTALL.vcxproj]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(14
>   9,5): error MSB3073: D:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake [D:\opencvcuda\opencv-master\bu
>   ild\INSTALL.vcxproj]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(14
>   9,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [D:\opencvcuda\opencv-master\build\INSTALL.vcxproj]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(14
>   9,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd [D:\opencvcuda\opencv-master\build\INSTALL.vcxproj]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(14
>   9,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [D:\opencvcuda\opencv-master\build\INSTA
>   LL.vcxproj]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(14
>   9,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [D:\opencvcuda\opencv-master\build\INSTALL.vcxproj]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(14
>   9,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1 [D:\opencvcuda\opencv-master\build\INSTALL.vcxproj]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(14
>   9,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone [D:\opencvcuda\opencv-master\build\INSTALL.vcxproj]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(14
>   9,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [D:\opencvcuda\opencv-master\build\INSTALL.vcxproj]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(14
>   9,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1. [D:\opencvcuda\opencv-master\build\INSTALL.vcxproj]

[image]

> CMake Error at modules/python3/cmake_install.cmake:44 (file):
>   file cannot create directory: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
>   Studio/Shared/Python37_64/Lib/site-packages/cv2.  Maybe need administrative
>   privileges.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):modules/cmake_install.cmake:189 (include)cmake_install.cmake:125 (include)
>   D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
>   D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: D:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake
>   D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
>   D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
>   D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
>   D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
>   D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
>   D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
>   D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
>   D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
>   Done building project "INSTALL.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
>   ========== Build: 195 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Please do not post errors as images. Post them as text. Images cannot be found by search and they make this question impossible for future visitors to find

Answer (score 0):

Solved with running the native x64 tools as adminstative.